# MATLAB: uicontrol and Lists

Tags: list, matlab, uicontrol

In MATLAB,
I have the following data:

```
mass = [ 23 45 44]
velocity = [34 53 32]
time = [1 2 3]
acceleration = [32 22 12]
speed = [12 33 44]
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to apply uicontrol that creates two lists with this data (mass, velocity, time, acceleration, speed), and have the ability to click on one of the variables (mass) in each column and there is a numerical data output, like mass = 23 45 44

Output: numerical data stored in these variables

Here is the code:

```
function learnlists()
figure;
yourcell={'mass','velocity','time','acceleration','speed'}
hb = uicontrol('Style', 'listbox','Position',[100 100 200 200],...
'string',yourcell,'Callback',@measurements)

yourcell={'mass','velocity','time','acceleration','speed'}
hc = uicontrol('Style', 'listbox','Position',[300 100 200 200],...
'string',yourcell,'Callback',@measurements)


function [out] = measurements(hb,evnt)
outvalue = get(hb,'value');

v = get(hb,'value')
if v == 1
    mass = [1 2  3 4 5]
elseif v == 2
     velocity = [ 1 2 3 4 5]

end

end

   end
```

Thanks,

Amanda

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand exactly what it is you're trying to do. if I select 'mass' do you want it to get the values `[23 45 44]`?  or what?

Comment: Can you explain what is the difference between the two lists? and what does datacollect function do?

Comment: Your code makes absolutely no sense to me, but you have a function (`datacollect`) nested within another function (`measurements`) that I'm pretty sure you're not wanting to do

Comment: I've been making adjustments.  We can ignore datacollect.  I just want to click on one value it outputs the data stored in that variable.

Comment: I still don't understand what it is you're trying to ultimately do here.

Comment: OK.  I want to create two lists of the variables (mass, velocity...).  This data has already been generated by another script.  But I want the capability to click on mass and it outputs the numerical data stored in that variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to not use a function to keep things simpler and keep all the variables in your base workspace.

Here is an example for one list box:

```
mass = [ 23 45 44];
velocity = [34 53 32];
time = [1 2 3];
acceleration = [32 22 12];
speed = [12 33 44];

figure;
yourcell = {'mass','velocity','time','acceleration','speed'};
hb = uicontrol('Style', 'listbox','Position',[100 100 200 200],...
     'string',yourcell,'Callback',...
     ['switch get(hb, ''Value''), ',...
     'case 1, mass, ',...
     'case 2, velocity, ',...
     'case 3, time, ',...
     'case 4, acceleration, ',...
     'case 5, speed, ',...
     'end']);
```

However this displays in command window, you could change the code to show it in a text box in your gui.

You can also execute a script as the Callback function.

```
hb = uicontrol('Style', 'listbox','Position',[100 100 200 200],...
     'string',yourcell,'Callback', 'myScript');
```

and then create an m-script in your directory:
(myScript.m)

```
switch get(hb, 'Value')
    case 1
        mass
    case 2
        velocity
    case 3
        time
    case 4
        acceleration
    case 5
        speed
end
```

Note that everything is still in your base workspace.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I know the code was not that self-explanatory.  So I appreciate you trying to understand what I was trying to do.